# How truncation works when applying BERT tokenizer on the batch of sentence pairs in HuggingFace?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

Say, I have three sample sentences:

```
s0 = "This model was pretrained using a specific normalization pipeline available here!"
s1 = "Thank to all the people around,"
s2 = "Bengali Mask Language Model for Bengali Language"
```

I could make a batch like:

```
batch = [[s[0], s[1]], [s[1], s[2]]]
```

Now, if I apply the **BERT** tokenizer on the sentence pairs, it truncates the sentence pairs if the length exceeds in such a way that the ultimate sum of the sentence pairs' lengths meets the `max_length` parameter, which was supposed to be done, okay. Here's what I meant:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = AutoModelForPreTraining.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

encoded = tokenizer(batch, padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=10)["input_ids"]
decoded = tokenizer.batch_decode(encoded)
print(decoded)

>>>Output: ['[CLS] this model was pre [SEP] thank to all [SEP]', '[CLS] thank to all [SEP] bengali mask language model [SEP]']
```

**My question is, how does the `truncation` work here in the pair of sentences where the number of tokens from each sentence of each pair is not equal?**

For example, in the first example output `'[CLS] this model was pre [SEP] thank to all [SEP]'` number of tokens from the two sentences has not come equally *i.e* **[CLS] 4 tokens [SEP] 3 tokens [SEP]**.

Answer (score 1):

There are different [truncation strategies](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__.truncation) you can choose from:

- **True** or **'longest_first'**: Truncate to a maximum length specified with the argument max_length or to the maximum acceptable input length for the model if that argument is not provided. This will truncate token by token, removing a token from the longest sequence in the pair if a pair of sequences (or a batch of pairs) is provided.
- **'only_first'**: Truncate to a maximum length specified with the argument max_length or to the maximum acceptable input length for the model if that argument is not provided. This will only truncate the first sequence of a pair if a pair of sequences (or a batch of pairs) is provided.
- **'only_second'**: Truncate to a maximum length specified with the argument max_length or to the maximum acceptable input length for the model if that argument is not provided. This will only truncate the second sequence of a pair if a pair of sequences (or a batch of pairs) is provided.
- **False** or **'do_not_truncate'** (default): No truncation (i.e., can output batch with sequence lengths greater than the model maximum admissible input size).